# Create Multiple ILeftBodyTouch Items in KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have an **MDList** in my script which is supposed to hold **OneLineAvatarIconListItems** with **MDCheckboxes** on their left. Now this is quite easy, however, I would like the ListItem to **have both a checkbox and an icon**. This is where it gets tricky.

I tried following the official kivymd docs but I didn't get the expected result, plus I had to figure some stuff out myself.

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
# It is kind of weird because if I don't import `OneLineLeftAdaptiveListItem`
# I will get a `KeyError: '_left_container'`
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
<MDCheckbox>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "48dp", "48dp"
<LeftContainer@ILeftBodyTouch+MDBoxLayout>:
    adaptive_width: True
    MDCheckbox:
    MDIconButton:
<OneLineLeftAdaptiveListItem@OneLineAvatarIconListItem>:
    on_size:
        self.ids._left_container.width = adaptive_container.width
        # self.ids._left_container.x = adaptive_container.width
        print(self.ids._left_container.width)
    LeftContainer:
        id: adaptive_container
MDList:
    OneLineLeftAdaptiveListItem:
        text: "First"
    OneLineLeftAdaptiveListItem:
        text: "Second"
    OneLineLeftAdaptiveListItem:
        text: "Third"
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Here is the result I get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

KivyMD List design under the Google Material Design Component Terms so you can not do that with KivyMD List Item but you can design your custom List Item Like following

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
# It is kind of weird because if I don't import `OneLineLeftAdaptiveListItem`
# I will get a `KeyError: '_left_container'`
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
<CustomOneLineListItem@MDBoxLayout>:
    text:''
    adaptive_height: True
    MDCheckbox
    MDIconButton
    OneLineListItem:
        text:root.text
<MDCheckbox>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "48dp", "48dp"
MDList:
    CustomOneLineListItem:
        text: "First"
    CustomOneLineListItem:
        text: "Second"
    CustomOneLineListItem:
        text: "Third"
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```